# JPA mapping @OneToOne own class

Tags: sql, database, jpa

Hello guys I have a problem mapping the typeOneToOne to its class. I have a Person class that a person is married and has an affair with the Same Person class but it is his wife. The foreign key is the name and surname.

```
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable{

@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="coniuge",referencedColumnName="NAME"),@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="coniuge",referencedColumnName="SURNAME")})
private Person coniuge = null;
@Id
@Column(name="NAME",nullable=false)
private String name;
@Id
@Column(name="SURNAME",nullable=false)
private String surname;
public Person getConiuge() {
return coniuge;}
```

The manager sevice:

```
public void aggiungiConiuge(Person coniugeA, Person coniugeB){
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        Person cA = manager.find(Person.class, coniugeA);
        Person cB = manager.find(Person.class, coniugeB);
        cA.setConiuge(cB);
        cB.setConiuge(cA);
        manager.merge(cA);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

how can I solve the problem ?? On DB does not create the two columns (foreign key) with keys Primare's partner (name and surname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems. 1, you are using PrimaryKeyJoinColumns instead of JoinColumns.  2, you specified a single "coniuge" field to be used as a foriegn key to referenced Person's Name and Surname fields.  You need to specify a field for each.

Try:

```
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="CONIUGE_NAME", referencedColumnName="NAME"),
      @JoinColumn(name="CONIUGE_SURNAME", referencedColumnName="SURNAME")})
  private Person coniuge;
```

This will allow you to keep using your current composite primary key.  Alan's solution below to generate a unique id field should be used instead where it can though.

Comment: this is the solution I was looking for !! Now you have to close the post or how it works here? 
Thank you, Zack.

Answer (score 1):

As forename/surname is not guaranteed to be unique use a surrogate key and map as below:

```
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) //or some other strategy
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "coniuge_id")
    private Person coniuge;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SURNAME", nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    public void setConiuge(Person coniuge) {
        this.coniuge = coniuge;
        coniuge.coniuge = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me error on "private Long id" since a another class (PersonPK) that defines the keys of the Person class, then the solution is to Chris

Comment: Have a PK based on someone's name is obviously ridiculous.

Comment: I agree, but they were just testing to learn how to use Hibernate, and the mappingsOneToOne,OneToMany etc etc.